# Guess a common 5-letter word!

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, rhyme

> Something with a very low pH,
>   though not alive, I evolve as I age.
>
> My grandfather was used in building;
>   My father, though smaller, was ground-breaking.
>   Though I'm smarter,
>   I'm not much safer,
>   for sometimes I'm crashing and burning

Please comment on how to improve! This may be my hardest one yet(though the brainpower of you guys here knows no boundaries)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are a

> **PHONE**

Something with a very low pH,

> A pH of ONE *(clever!)*

though not alive, I evolve as I age.

> Phones have evolved from the time of A. Graham Bell

My grandfather was used in building;

> Landlines/fixed line phones

My father, though smaller, was ground-breaking.

> Mobile phone, ground-breaking as it offered portability
>  Alternatively, the earliest mobile phones were big/heavy enough to break the ground if dropped

Though I'm smarter,

> Currently, we're on smart phones

I'm not much safer,
for sometimes I'm crashing and burning

> These phones crash at times, or even burn/explode due to faulty batteries (e.g. Note7).
>  There are also privacy concerns associated with phones, due to malicious apps, etc. and safety concerns due to its usage while driving/walking.

Comment: honestly I meant to say 'used in building' as in a brick or something. The earliest phones were called bricks.

Comment: Fair enough, @KarisYuen :-)

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Basic? (a common 5-letter word, for sure)

Something with a very low pH,

> In chemistry, a basic compound is one... with very high pH. (It has very low concentration of hydrogen ions, but pH is a reverse log scale.) Oh well. I'm banking on this being a typo.

though not alive, I evolve as I age.

> "basic" also can mean at a low level; as you learn, you can get more advanced.

My grandfather was used in building;

> Now we let BASIC be a programming language. It was indirectly influenced by Assembly. (i.e. "building")

My father, though smaller, was ground-breaking.

> FORTRAN is ground-breaking and a highly influential programming language. Also, as time goes by and computational power goes up, computers start getting smaller.

Though I'm smarter,
I'm not much safer,
for sometimes I'm crashing and burning

> BASIC is a high-level programming language but can still crash.

Comment: Mhh. And there was me looking for acids which had been used in building or mining.

Comment: I wonder if the father is the ["Visual" variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic), as it was ground-breaking by opening it up to amateurs/hobbyists. And that makes me wonder if "I'm smarter not much safer" is the ["scripting" variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) as that didn't have type safety.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't the answer I was looking for. To help out, the first line isn't literal. Good try though! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Since low ph is acidic, and acidic is sharp, and we have language C, C++ and C#, C++ was ground breaking, and C# is "smarter" than C++, is the answer sharp?

Comment: Nice try, but there was already a correct answer, which is the accepted one.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, Robert Verrill! Congratulations on your first answer as well! Do take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), and we look forward to your continued participation & contributions.